# File Upload form validation

Tags: validation, laravel-4

I'm working with Laravel 4.1 and I'm trying to use the built in Validator options to restrict the size of an uploaded file to 2mb.

However when I test the validation with an overlarge file (10mb), the validation doesn't fire. Instead Input::all() is completely empty, causing other errors to occur.

Is there something I'm missing about form validation with files?

Here's the validator that I'm using

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), 
    array(
        'submission_status'      => 'required',
        'photo'                  => 'required_if:submission_status,Received|max:1200',
    ),
    $messages
);
```

Template Code - Uses Twig as the template engine

```
{{ form_open({'url': request_url(), 'method': 'post', 'role': 'form', 'name': 'photo_form', 'id': 'photo-form', 'enctype': 'multipart/form-data'})|raw }}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            Please submit a photo of just yourself. A head-and-shoulders photo works well.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            {{ form_radio('submission_status', 'Received', false, {'id': 'photo-now', 'required': 'required', 'aria-describedby': 'submission-status-error'})|raw }} Upload photo now (The file should be no larger than 1.2 megabytes, and in jpeg format)<br />
            {{ form_radio('submission_status', 'Photo by Web promised', false, {'id': 'photo-later', 'required': 'required', 'aria-describedby': 'submission-status-error'})|raw }} Upload photo later<br />
            {{ form_radio('submission_status', 'No photo desired', false, {'id': 'no-photo', 'required': 'required', 'aria-describedby': 'submission-status-error'})|raw }} No photo desired<br />
            <span class="error" id="submission-status-error"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="photo-now-form">
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p>Please select a photograph of <b>just</b> yourself in jpeg format.<br />
                    <ul>
                        <li>Filenames must have a ".jpg" extension (e.g., myphoto.jpg).</li>
                        <li>The image should be about 4 x 5 inches and have a resolution of 200 pixels per inch.</li>
                        <li>The jpeg file should be between 500 and 1,200 kilobytes (0.5 to 1.2 MB).</li>
                    </ul>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                {{ form_file('photo', {'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'photo', 'required': 'required'})|raw }}
            </div>
        </div> <!-- row -->
    </div>
    <hr />

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            {{ form_hidden('_id', candidate._id, {'class': 'form-control', 'id': '_id'})|raw }}
            {{ form_hidden("candidate_id", candidate.candidate_id, {'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'candidate-id'})|raw }}

            {{ form_hidden('page', page, {'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'page'})|raw }}
            {{ form_submit('Submit', {'id': 'save-questionnaire', 'class': 'form-control btn btn-primary'})|raw }}
        </div>
    </div>
{{ form_close()|raw }}
```

Thanks!
--Lisa

Comment: Could you post your HTML of the form please.

Comment: Would the raw template be more useful, or the rendered HTML?

Comment: I dont really know twig, but i don't see any "name" attributes in your form. Comment out your file upload field, and try with a normal field until `Input::all()` contains somethin.

Comment: I can upload smaller file sizes without issue. I think this is coming about when file sizes are bigger than what PHP will allow, and I'm not sure how to compensate for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59684/discussion-between-reflic-and-lisa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being an issue less with the form and more with the PHP settings handling file uploads. I ultimately didn't come up with a resolution to the issue, since it's not feasible to remove restrictions on upload file sizes in the php.ini file.

Since the form use is restricted to a very limited set of users, I am putting a pin in this issue for now.